# Feature Scaling with Octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression

I want to do feature scaling datasets by using means and standard deviations, and my code is below; but apparently it is not a univerisal code, since it seems only work with one dataset. Thus I am wondering what is wrong with my code, any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

X is the dataset I am currently using.

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
m = size(X, 1);
mu_matrix = ones(m, 1) * mu;
sigma_matrix = ones(m, 1) * sigma;
featureNormalize = (X-mu_matrix)/sigma;
```

Comment: A couple of questions to help you. What do the dimensions in X mean (presumably rows are observations, and columns are features). Secondly, what do you undestand is happening by the lines defining mu_matrix and sigma_matrix? Finally, are you sure your operations involve `*` and `/` rather than `.*` and `./`, and do you understand the difference between the two?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. First question, yes-the rows are observations, and columns are features. Secondly, I think what I did with mu_matrix and sigma_matrix, is to create mu and standard deviations matrix that are the same size of X, by also put 1s into the first column. Third, with the function of     .* and  ./ is  take each element of matrix for calculation. I also tried to use  .* and ./ in my code, but it doesn't work. I feel like I understand something, but don't get the whole thing right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying what you think the code should be doing in the comments.

My answer will effectively answer why what you think is happening is not what is happening.

First let's talk about the `mean` and `std` functions. When their input is a *vector* (whether this is vertically or horizontally aligned), then this will return a single number which is the mean or standard deviation of that vector respectively, as you might expect.

However, when the input is a *matrix*, then you need to know what it does differently. Unless you *specify* the direction (dimension) in which you should be calculating means / std, then it will calculate means along the rows, i.e. returning a single number for each column. Therefore, the end-result of this operation will be a **horizontal** vector.

Therefore, both `mu` and `sigma` will be *horizontal vectors* in your code.

Now let's move on to the 'matrix multiplication' operator (i.e. `*`).
When using the matrix multiplication operator, if you multiply a horizontal vector with a vertical vector (i.e. the usual matrix multiplication operation), your output is a single number (i.e. a scalar). However, if you reverse the orientations, as in, you multiply a vertical vector by a horizontal one, you will in fact be calculating a 'Kronecker product' instead. Since the output of the `*` operation is completely defined by the rows of the first input, and the columns of the second input, whether you're getting a matrix multiplication or a kronecker product is implicit and entirely dependent on the orientation of your inputs.

Therefore, in your case, the line `mu_matrix = ones(m, 1) * mu;` is not in fact appending a vector of ones, like you say. It is in fact performing the kronecker product between a vertical vector of ones, and the horizontal vector that is your `mu`, effectively creating an `m-by-n` matrix with mu repeated vertically for m rows.

Therefore, at the end of this operation, as the variable naming would suggest, `mu_matrix` is in fact a matrix (same with `sigma_matrix`), having the same size as `X`.

Your final step is `X- mu_sigma`, which gives you at each element, the difference between x and mu at that element. Then you "divide" with the sigma matrix.

Here is why I asked if you were sure you should be using `./` instead of `/`.

`/` is the *matrix division* operator. With `/` You are effectively performing matrix multiplication by an inverse matrix, since D / S is mathematically equivalent to D * inv(S). It seems to me you should be using `./` instead, to simply divide each element by the standard deviation of that column (which is why you had to repeat the horizontal vector over m rows in `sigma_matrix`, so that you could use it for 'elementwise division'), since what you are trying to do is to normalise each row (i.e. observation) of a particular column, by the standard deviation that is specific to that column (i.e. feature).

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detail and clear explanation, I do realize some confusion of mine comes from the unclear understanding of how multiplication works for matrix and vector. However, when I tried to fix my code, I still got stuck with the last line. I know it should be something like
 `featureNormalize = (X-mu_matrix)./sigma_matrix `
if I understand you correctly. But this code still doesn't work for universal dataset. Or it just proves that I still get some ideas wrong...

Comment: it should work as long as you're dealing with an X which has observations as rows and features as columns.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot Tasos, I really appreciate your effort to help me. After I submit my code to the coursera system, it still doesn't let me pass, but since I don't know other ways to fix it, and what you said also make sense, I would think it probably something to do with the grading system of coursera.

Thanks again :)

Comment: @Catsitter obviously, I don't know the specifics of your submission, but one random thought is that maybe your exercise expects you to apply the 'bias' term after you've performed feature scaling. Note that the feature scaling performed above only involves the original features so far. In general one then also appends a bias term after feature scaling (i.e. append a column of 'ones' to the matrix of scaled features).